# Can a WCF Service be used the same way a socket connection is used?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I currently have a windows application that contains a chart control. The app connects to a socket (TCP/IP) on a server.

On connect, the server sends out 100 records through a byte stream.

On receive, the application deciphers the byte stream into a data table.

The application then plots various records from that table into the chart control.

The application asynchronously listens on the connection for more information.

The server, as it collects data through various services, will send out just one record at a time as it gets updates.

The application receives these updates, deciphers them, updates the data table and updates the chart control.

My question:

We would like to make the Windows application into a Web application. We would like to develop a WCF service on the server to update the web page in real time (as it does now in the windows app), but using XML.

I have not used WCF before, and as I have been researching, it seems to me that the client would have to initiate the update at timed intervals. That the WCF service wouldn't be able to contact the client when it receives an updated record. Is this correct, or have I missed something? Any suggestions you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can expose of a WCF service on your client and from the server you can invoke the call to this service when you want to update. Also worth looking into REST services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a duplex service and callbacks, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) article details it a bit.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it's just what I needed. I don't know how I missed it!